# Certificate for this server is invalid iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, alamofire

I am getting this error "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “abc.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."
I already added exception domain.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>myURL/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>


func userLoginRequest(parameters:Parameters, viewController: UIViewController,
                      completion:@escaping (_ result:String)->(),
                      errorHandler:@escaping (_ result:Error,_ statusCode:Int?)->()) {
    Alamofire.request(KLoginUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .validate()
        .responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Login>) in
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                let value = response.result.value
                if value!.status!{
                    completion((value?.message)!)
                }
                else{
                    KRProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    ConstantFile.errorMsg(errorMsg: value!.message!, viewController: viewController)
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                KRProgressHUD.dismiss()
                errorHandler(error, response.response?.statusCode)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think your problem about HTTPS but your plist seems correct. Do you use Alamofire ? 
Be sure that abc.com support HTTPS

Comment: Yes i am uisng Alamofire and i tried url on postman is working fine and url is https:// abc.com. Even i tried with http:// also but no success.

Comment: can you share your code where Alamofire make request ?

Comment: @DrainOpener i added my code in question.

Comment: Show us the value of KLoginUrl (and redact any API keys or sensitive info)

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Value for KLoginUrl https:// abc.com/corpopanel/api/login

Comment: @DrainOpener EmilioPelaez thanks guys. Issue resolved actually backend SSL certificate got revoked.

Comment: @RahulGupta happy to hear maybe you wish to post your answer for community.